# Excel VBA: Looking up user input value in another table fails for String/Variant types

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a code that would look up a string value (that I would get from the user) from a table located in another sheet of my workbook.

I've tried using the `Range.Find` function as well as `Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup`.

```
Sub ID_Lookup()

Dim name As Variant
Dim FoundID As Range
Dim test_tbl As ListObject

Set test_tbl = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Full_List")

name = InputBox("Enter ID name:")

'Snippet used to find user input value above located in table from another sheet. 
On Error Resume Next
  FoundID = test_tbl.DataBodyRange.Find(name, LookAt:=xlWhole)
' FoundID = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, test_tbl .DataBodyRange, 1, False)
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

While the logic above seems to work well for numerical values, it returns an error (in case of Vlookup) and Null (in case of Range.Find) while trying to find string values.

The string values I need to lookup are sometimes a combination of letters, numbers and a period character (for example: AB.CDE2) and I have tried setting the user input to both String and Variant datatypes to no avail. The column from where I would search is also Text ('General' format in Excel).

Any direction would be helpful.

Comment: `FoundID` is declared as a `Range` object, so you should be using `Set FoundID = ...`

Comment: Oh wow, that was super silly of me. Thank you so much, it works perfectly now!